# how to use mutate_if to change values

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I use `mutate_if()` to change values of `b` to `NA` in case `a > 25`

I can do it with `ifelse` but I feel `mutate_if` is created for such task.

```
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(a = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 10, 60),
              b = c(12, 23, 34, 45, 56, 67))
```

Comment: Maybe `case_when()` or `if_else()` would be better for this example.

Comment: `mutate_if` is meant to select entire columns and apply some operation to them. It does not apply a conditional statement to the individual elements in a column. `mutate` with an `ifelse` is probably what you want. If you want to apply that operation to multiple columns, see `across`.

Comment: okay I got it, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this small example, I'm not sure that you actually need `mutate_if()`. `mutate_if` is designed to use the `_if` part to determine which columns to subset and work on, rather than an `if` condition when modifying a value.

Rather, you can use `mutate_at()` to select your columns to operate on - either based on their exact name or by using `vars(contains('your_string'))`.

See the help page for more info on the `mutate_*` functions: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html

Here are 3 options, using `mutate()` and `mutate_at()`:

```
# using mutate()
tbl %>% 
  mutate(
    b = ifelse(a > 25, NA, b)
  )

# mutate_at - we select only column 'b'
tbl %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(c('b')), ~ifelse(a > 25, NA, .))

# select only columns with 'b' in the col name
tbl %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains('b')), ~ifelse(a > 25, NA, .))
```

Which all produce the same output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    12
2    20    23
3    30    NA
4    40    NA
5    10    56
6    60    NA
```

I know it's not `mutate_if`, but I suspect you don't actually need it.

Comment: `mutate_if`, `mutate_all`, and `mutate_at` are superceded in favor of `mutate` with `across`

Comment: Yep this is true, I've gotta make the switch soon!

Answer (score 4):

The mutate_if() variant applies a predicate function (a function that
returns TRUE or FALSE) to determine the relevant subset of columns. So the mutate_if condition will apply to all columns and in the example provided below, you can see it uses. Examples of usage is performing an mathematical operation on numeric fields, etc.

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html

```
function (.tbl, .predicate, .funs, ...)

library(dplyr)

# Below code gets the job done but as Hugh Allan explained it is probably not 
  the right approach

tbl %>%
  mutate_if(colnames(tbl) != 'a', ~ifelse(a > 25, NA, .))

# A tibble: 6 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    12
2    20    23
3    30    NA
4    40    NA
5    10    56
6    60    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
tbl %>%
      mutate(b = replace(b, a > 25, NA))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1    10    12
2    20    23
3    30    NA
4    40    NA
5    10    56
6    60    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

And for completion here is base R and `data.table` variant.

```
tbl$b[tbl$a > 25] <- NA
tbl

#     a     b
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1    10    12
#2    20    23
#3    30    NA
#4    40    NA
#5    10    56
#6    60    NA
```

In `data.table` -

```
library(data.table)
setDT(tbl)
tbl[a > 25, b := NA]
tbl
```